# Is there a word for multiplying and dividing two terms in a product by the same value?

Tags: factoring

Obviously doing this is a form of /simplifying/, but I'd like to know if there's a specific term for this kind of multiplication.   For example, given $k = 2n$, you know $6k = 12n$, but is there a term for this?

Answer (score 1):

The term that you are looking for is probably *multiplicative cancelation* (or some variant thereof).  If the objects that you are working with are "sufficiently nice" (the real numbers, for example), then the property of multiplicative cancellation is the statement
\begin{equation}
a\ne 0 \text{ and } b = c
\iff ab = ac.
\end{equation}
Given something of the form $ab = ac$, you can *cancel* the $a$ on each side and not alter the identity (note that this is an idea that is somewhat distinct from "dividing both sides by $a$", though the distinction may not matter until you get into higher maths).  In your particular example, you might write
\begin{equation}
k = \frac{6}{6} k = \frac{1}{6} 6k
\quad\text{and}\quad 2n = \frac{6}{6} 2n = \frac{1}{6} 12n.
\end{equation}
Then
\begin{equation}
k = 2n
\iff \frac{1}{6} 6k = \frac{1}{6} 12n
\iff 6k = 12n,
\end{equation}
where the last identity is obtained by canceling the factor of $1/6$ (or, if you prefer, dividing both sides by 6).

Answer (score 1):

This is known as [multiplication property of equality](http://intermath.coe.uga.edu/dictnary/descript.asp?termID=434).

Multiplication property of equality states that when both sides of an equation are multiplied by the same number, the remaining expressions are still equal.